# fgetcsv dies on live instance on dev not -- where to look

Tags: php, fastcgi, fgetcsv

I have identical live and dev instances on the same server
(seperated by fastcgi with an identical php.ini)

i run in a script the command
`while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ";")) !== FALSE) {`

on the dev instance the command runs without problems
44000 lines, uses up to 200MB of memory (of 512MB given)

on the live instance it runs up to line 28700
and crashes the script without output
with 133MB of memory used

i put the command in a "try" but no error is thrown

where could i look next

**UPDATE**
it crashes without output (blank page)
i execute it from a http page
the script just stops when returning to the while statement 
(narrowed down by writing to a file the state)
it's a dedicated server

**UPDATE2**
forgot the php error log :/
-- according to it, it seems like i exhausted the memory though it's weird ..

Comment: What's inside the loop? Anything you can free?

Comment: _'It crashes'_ .. how? Fatal error? Segfault? Specifics please.

Comment: what's on line 28700 ? loading or transforming a big dataset?

Comment: You could check with `phpinfo()` that you do have the settings set as you expect and they aren't overwritten by something else later.

Comment: Could be memory. Maybe memory allocation is larger in dev. Look at ini_get("memory_limit");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check your PHP error logs. Depending on your configuration your PHP errors may show in your web server logs or in a dedicated PHP log file.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

Comment: the answer was that the *web and *cli php were given different amounts of ram. in this case the *web had more than the *cli php. so when the script was started manually via the web interface it worked - when the schedule was set (also in the web interface) it used the *cli php through cron which had just 128mb allocated.

Comment: I'm pleased you fixed it and thanks for reporting back on the solution.